# How to wrap model in viewmodel and use it in datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am developing a wpf application with MVVM.

For now, I have my model entities, one viewmodel per views and of course views.

There is examples of my entities:

```
public class Group : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string GID { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}

public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

(I removed notifications to simplify)

Currently, I map my model entities to viewmodel throught an intermediate class which repeat properties of model and add some others. To summary: model <-> component <-> viewmodel. But this add more useless complexity for me.

In addition I have a special case where I want to show a list of person in a datagrid.

[You can see here in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehSkc.png)

As you can see, Group column is a dropdown filtered by start date and end date and Level column is filtered based on selected group in the previous dropdown.

**So, my question is: How do you wrap your model by viewmodel ? And specialy with this case.**

Comment: You may simply derive the view model classes from model classes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I tried this way and I was with this kind of classes: `class PersonViewModel : Person{}` and `class GroupViewModel : Group{}` but I had to hide the group property of Person to have a GroupViewModel property. 

So, I am not sure it's the best way or perhaps I am wrong somewhere :)

Comment: I can't see the image as I am behind a proxy. What if you would derive the component class from your model class and then expose the collection of components in your viewmodel to Bind them in your View?

Comment: It's like you are in my mind as I done exactly that xD
However I found a simpler solution. 
I created a viewmodel `class PersonViewModel{}` which wrap my model `class Person{}` + properties needed by the view. 
And my "MainViewModel" wrap a collection of "PersonViewModel" to bind to a datagrid. 
That avoid the creation of components. 
I done that based on [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained) a colleague shared with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a simple solution based on [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained) I colleague shared with me.

```
public class PersonViewModel(){
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel(){
    public Club Club { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> PersonViewModels { get; set;}
    public PersonViewModel CurrentPersonViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

That's perhaps not perfect but this avoid too much complexity in my solutions.